# Does material icon have an icon for resize-full

Tags: material-design, google-material-icons

Wondering if there is an icon in Material Icons to use for resizing . Like this which is available in Font Awesome

[image]

http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/icon/resize-full/

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

aspect_ratio
zoom out map
fullscreen